# Sinatra CSS/Images Issue

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a sinatra app running locally and awhile back I ran into an issue when I went to add styling. I placed the CSS file in `public/css/style.css` but it wasn't being served. After some troubleshooting I discovered the `Rack::Static` middleware and that solved the problem at the time, the line I added in `config.ru` was:

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/css", "/images"], :root => "public"
```

This lets Rack serve the css and images from `public/css` and `public/images` respectively. When you link up images or styles in Haml you just use `css/style.css` and leave the public off.

The issue I have after last night, I created a small file structure inside of my views directory to better organize things, so now when you visit the /contact/new path which renders `views/contacts/_form.haml` the CSS doesn't work. Viewing source on the page confirms that Rack is attempting to serve the CSS at `contacts/css/style.css` instead of the correct path of `css/style.css` such as the main index correctly displays.

How can I fix this to make sure it's always rendering from the root of the URL and not based on the relative location of the view currently being rendered? I tried making `root => "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)/public"` in `config.ru` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the location of the view template should make any difference but if you have relative URLs like `css/style.css` then the browser will append this to the path part of the URL of the page that hosts it. So if the page URL is `contact/new` the effective URL becomes `contact/css/style.css`.

If you prefix the relative URL with a '/' like `/css/style.css` it should be relative to the root path of the site which you are mapping to the public directory. So that might be the best way to go:

```
  %link{ :href => '/css/style.css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :type => 'text/css' }
```

I haven't tried using the rackup file to configure static files. This is what works for me in the application itself:

```
  set :static, true
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  set :public, 'public'
```

But I think that Sinatra will serve static files from the public by default so I don't think the last line is required.

Answer (score 0):

**simple way to show images**

get '/notes/images/:file' do

send_file('/root/dev/notes/images/'+params[:file], :disposition => 'inline')

end

Comment: '/root/dev/notes/images/' means whatever you file/image directory

Answer (score 0):

I am putting css files in `public/css/`

and using the following redirection for other pathes

```
get %r{.*/css/style.css} do
    redirect('css/style.css')
end
```